# styles unlimited value image fields

Tags: 7, media

I use unlimited values for image field in a content type, then the images displays one below the other :

[image]

Is there a way to render this field differently?
For example every line show me only three images.

Im using `display_suite` module to display the node content.

Comment: Yep, that would would be [CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Overview.en.html)...

Comment: Yes, that must be with css ;) but how can I wrap every three items of that field with a div. Because if I don't group items togother, and float left every single item, it will be a mess in the page :)

Comment: They would traditionally be wrapped in `<div>`s with `field-...` classes, if not maybe your theme defines a field.tpl.php which overrides that? Either way, the [Fences module](https://drupal.org/project/fences) would probably help out. On each field settings page you can define the tags that should wrap each item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS. Your fieldset should be wrapped in one big div, with each field-item wrapped in it's own div. I see no reason you couldn't do this with CSS alone.

Unless there's a specific reason you need each line to be exactly three images. In that case you would have to override the field template: https://drupal.org/node/1089656

Then you would have to write some basic PHP logic that counts the number of field items and print those out in a 1X3 display.

Comment: This what I need exactly, it's a custom template for my field (I know that it can be done with css but it's not enough for my case...) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding CSS for the row

.class-of-the-row { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.3333%;
}